# Scrapy extract table from website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am a Python novice and am trying to write a script to extract the data from this [page](http://www.dairy.com/market-prices/?page=quote&sym=DAH15&mode=i). Using scrapy, I wrote the following code:

```
import scrapy

class dairySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dairy_price"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://www.dairy.com/market-prices/?page=quote&sym=DAH15&mode=i',

        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)




    def parse(self, response):
        for rows in response.xpath("//tr"):
            yield {
                'text': rows.xpath(".//td/text()").extract().strip('. \n'),

                }
```

However, this didn't scrape anything. Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The table on the page http://www.dairy.com/market-prices/?page=quote&sym=DAH15&mode=i is being dynamically added to the `DOM` by making request to  http://shared.websol.barchart.com/quotes/quote.php?page=quote&sym=DAH15&mode=i&domain=blimling&display_ice=&enabled_ice_exchanges=&tz=0&ed=0.

You should be scrapping the second link instead of first. As `scrapy.Request` will only return html source code and not the content added using javascript.

**UPDATE**

Here is the working code for extracting table data

```
import scrapy

class dairySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dairy_price"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            "http://shared.websol.barchart.com/quotes/quote.php?page=quote&sym=DAH15&mode=i&domain=blimling&display_ice=&enabled_ice_exchanges=&tz=0&ed=0",
        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.css(".bcQuoteTable tbody tr"):
            print row.xpath("td//text()").extract()
```

Make sure you edit your `settings.py` file and change `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True` to `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False`

Comment: Thanks,  i replaced the URL by the second link . But the scrapper doesn't work , data on the table are not scrapped . My xpaths aren't correct , how can I select the good xpaths for my rows ?

Comment: I tried using the second link, the issue is that the robots.txt file on the second link doesn't allow scrapy to work. To fix this, add change ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True in your settings.py to ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False.

Comment: This will at least make sure that you get response from the website and your parse callback function will get called.

Comment: I updated my answer to help you with the table extraction.